# How does rep increase and get displayed? Why should I register, and can I keep earned rep if I do?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-accounts, unregistered-users, sign-up

I'm not a registered user. I have seven reputation and eight posts. If I register an account on Stack Overflow, will my reputation and post ownership be reset, or will they carry over to the registered account?

I'd also like to know about the rating system on Stack Overflow. How does reputation increase?

Additionally, I see some numbers displayed for every user (for me it's 7.1). The first number is the user's reputation; what do the other numbers represent?

Finally, what is the benefit of registering on Stack Overflow? After all, one can ask questions here without registering.

Comment: candidate for faq tag?

Answer (score 7):

> How does the reputation increase?

See the FAQ, "[What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)"

> for me it's 7.1 , the first number is the reputation and whare are the other numbers?

The `7` is your current reputation, and the `.1` is actually your badge count (you currently have 1 Bronze badge). See the [Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges).

> what is the benifit of registering in stackoverflow.

Registering has many benefits if you use StackOverflow (or any of the Stack Exchange sites) frequently; off the top of my head, a few benefits would be: you can add favorite tags (or ignored tags), you can receive notification of comments/responses to your questions, you can gain more privileges as your reputation increases (see link to FAQ above), and generally become more involved in the community (which is where the real value of SO/SE lies).

Comment: Almost complete but I would consider adding rep is retained after registering and that another benefit is that unregistered accounts are Cookie based. If you access from another computer SO won't know that it is the same person and you won't be able to accept answers to your questions. If you register an account you can log in.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the faq, in the top of the page: https://stackoverflow.com/faq