# Submitting inline edits works, but appears to fail

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, inline-editor

At least two people have encountered a display bug with inline edits. After the editor presses the **Submit** button, the edit form remains on the editor's screen, and the three-dot "work in progress" icon continues flashing indefinitely. However, the edit does actually get saved in the system, and is visible to other users. This was initially reported [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/inline-edit-bug):

> T: Anyone want to give a go at re-titling [[this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98143/question-about-stack-overflow-user-account-registration)]? There are too many questions there for me to come up with something sensible.
>
> ...
>
> P: I attempted to submit "How does rep increase and get displayed? Why should I register, and can I keep earned rep if I do?" but it's not going through.
>
> T: It did go through
>
> P: But the real answer is to tell the user "don't ask multiple questions in one post."
>
> T: Interestingly enough, I also had that problem (where it just hung there).
>
> P: Interesting indeed, I'm still seeing the three-dot "loading" icon thingy and the edit box.
>
> T: Yeah, I think there might be a bit of an issue.

EDIT 1:
This was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) yesterday, but the fix is incomplete. I just inline-edited [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98331/will-i-get-punished-for-doing-not-exactly-fair-thing-to-get-badge) one minute ago, and did not see my changes take effect after I hit **Save Edits**. Unlike before, the edit form did go away, and the three-dot "working" icon did not stay on the screen. A standard page refresh solved the problem.

EDIT 2, 15 seconds after submitting edit 1:
When I submitted edit 1, the new content loaded immediately.

Comment: I thought it was just my system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently jQuery parses the `\r\n` linefeed between `#question` and `#question-status` (since that question was migrated) in the response as a text node, which causes an exception when `.hide()` is invoked on the jQuery set in the success handler for the edit submission.

Comment: I trust you, but would appreciate it if you could tell me how to independently check this, just for my own general fund of knowledge.

Comment: @PopularDemand: If you take my word for it: He's right :)

Comment: @balpha, again, it's not about him being right or wrong; it's about me learning how to debug. I am well aware of Tim's SE-debugging prowess.

Comment: [Link for my own reference](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/jquery-debugging)

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 issues here already fixed for the next deploy:

- posts that have been closed error as you say
- editing on some mobile devices gives a 404

and probably a few others. These are all fixed pending deployment.