# Will I get punished for doing a... not-exactly-fair thing to get badges?

Tags: discussion, badges, ban

Will I get punished if I use my votes quickly to "run" for badges?

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/147/vox-populi
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/118/suffrage

My goal is purely to get the above badges.

I'll just select random questions and upvote those I think are good.

Comment: Isn't that the point of those badges?  You won't get banned or punished for doing something that the dev team intended you to do.

Comment: @Kyle Trauberman so @mmyers is joking ?

Comment: yes.  he was being sarcastic.  you are encouraged to use all your votes in a day.  You are encouraged to post good answers, and you are encouraged to use the site to its full potential.

Comment: okay :D Sorry I didn'T get it first time I read it :D I'm noob :D Okay, going to obtain my badges :p

Comment: Go have fun. :)

Comment: Where is that avatar from, @genesis? For a second there, I thought you were [R. Bemrose](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15880/r-bemrose).

Comment: @Popular It's an [official Valve avatar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1291257#1291257 "This exchange has nothing to do with genesis, it just happens to be a convenient discussion of this very avatar") of the Spy from *Team Fortress 2*. Apparently it's actually fairly common.

Comment: Thanks, @Grace! Of course TF2 had to be the one Orange Box game I never played....

Comment: @Popular Demand: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Spy/no -> http://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/images/thumb/e/eb/Buffed_red_spy.jpg/128px-Buffed_red_spy.jpg

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Those badges are there to get you to vote. If you vote to get the badges, *of course* you will be punished severely. Also, we hate it when people post amazing answers just to try for silver or gold badges.

Comment: I used all my votes the other day to get vox populi, and the next day I found that all my votes were refunded and I was able to vote again.  I got to keep the badge though.  Bug?

Comment: I don't mean I would just run throught questions and vote them ALL up, just those I think they're good.

Comment: @mmyers who was talking about posting answers?

Comment: @genesis, he's being sarcastic.

Comment: I believe everyone should listen to their inner Shog[9](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5314/should-sarcasm-be-acceptable/5318#5318).

Comment: You votes no longer registered as having clicked them?  Have evidence -- yes, post as bug.

Comment: @Kyle, you get a quantity of votes per day, so the next day your quota is refilled and you can vote again.

Comment: @RivieraKid: Kyle was making a point. He knows perfectly well how the voting system works.

Comment: How many people upvoting that answer have noticed the sarcasm? At least I hope, it's a sarcasm ;)

Answer (score 24):

Key phrase (emphasis added):

> ...upvote those **I think they're good**

If you were just spraying your votes all over any old garbage posts I'd frown deeply, but honestly there's not much more I could do about it than that.  As long as you're voting up things that you think are good, you're using your votes as they were intended to be used.