# "This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities."

Tags: discussion, voting, account-suspension

I know that there are several questions for this, but this is user-specific, so please do not consider this question as EXACT duplicate.

User [Ham and Bacon](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8183/ham-and-bacon#qpage_1-anpage_1-qsort_newest-ansort_votes) was suspended, for "voting irregularities". What does it mean. Did he voted up himself with another account or is that because of his questions? [His reputation increases fast](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/8183/ham-and-bacon?tab=reputation) and I see no problem with him. He always helped me with my problems & most of his answers are great

Comment: Might have been better to ask on their meta, as you'd have to have one of their mods here to answer this with details about that specific user.

Comment: Eh, you're getting answers.  Wait a bit (you might get what you're looking for), maybe go flag something on their meta and ask them to come look over here.  If you don't, flag for migration.

Comment: I could flag random post to tell them to come here? Isn't that dangerous?

Comment: No.  You might lose some flag weight on the site, but that's nothing to worry about.  No, seriously, don't worry about it.  Flag one of your own posts, or one of the user in question's posts.

Comment: Related: [Avoid the Streisand effect: be clear about the reason when suspending an account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-accoun).

Comment: Wow he changed his name since but he's still banned!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The details of a suspension are private, the moderators involved won't tell you much about it. If the user in question wants to reveal anything himself, he is free to do so. But otherwise the exact details of the suspension will be considered private.

Comment: I do not want EXACT reason, but possible reasons how can user be suspended for "voting irregularities” Bit related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98331/will-i-get-punished-for-doing-a-not-exactly-fair-thing-to-get-badges

Comment: @genesis In almost all cases this means the user created sock puppets to upvote his main account. It might also be used for repeated malicious downvoting sprees, but that is pretty rare.

Comment: @Fabian: AFAIK there isn't an official sanction on letting out details about a suspension.

Comment: @Won't I always thought it would violate the moderator agreement, I consider any information about a user that is not easily accessible to a non-moderator private. It is also not the kind of information I think anybody really needs to know, if the user in question wants to discuss it he is free to do so, else I think anything the mods could say won't help anyone.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Fabian. While I haven't seen an official sanction, I think this is one of those "implied" things. Sensitive information about users shouldn't be disclosed by moderators to the community at large unless absolutely necessary. However, the user in question is free to do so (or grant permission) at his or her own choice.

Comment: @CodyGray: You can, however, see that a user has been suspended, and the reason why.  There isn't much information left to know at this point.  This user posted many low quality questions, that one made a rude comment, the other sockpuppeted.  What else is there to say?  The only advantage mods have is that they can see a user's history.  Everything else is out in the open.

Answer (score 27):

Voting irregularities include also votes done from a user (who could not be even using two different accounts) to other users.
Suppose a user up-votes twenty posts made from the same user in a minute; the system will detect the situation, and automatically remove the votes.

The same applies to other voting patterns including, as you said, a user who uses two different accounts to vote other users, or to vote (from a secondary account) the posts created with the main account. (In short, the second case would be a way for the user to vote himself.)

If the user keeps doing the same thing more than once, then moderators would temporary suspended the account.

As down-votes on questions don't influence the reputation of who votes, in the same way up-votes do, you could not notice any change in the reputation of who has been caught with vote irregularities.

Comment: so it was probably system ?

Comment: I don't think it is automatic. As far as I know, an account suspension is never automatic, except for suspension from asking questions on an SE site.

Comment: Little bit related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98331/will-i-get-punished-for-doing-a-not-exactly-fair-thing-to-get-badges might this be exactly that reason?

Comment: @genesis I think it's not that the reason, also because there are few badges that you get basing on your how many times you vote.

Comment: but downvotes do influence the reputation of the voter don't they? they get a -1 and the other i suppose gets a -2

Comment: @barlop If you down-vote a question, your reputation doesn't change; it changes only if you down-vote an answer.