# Which moderator election was decided with the smallest margin?

Tags: support, election

How 'close' can ♦ moderator elections on Stack Exchange get? Has there been an election where a single vote would have made the difference? [The Spring 2018 election on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365198/4751173) was quite close, percentage-wise; the final difference between the remaining candidates was 17 votes (only 0.05% of the number of ballots). One of the most recent pro-tempore elections, on [Drones Stack Exchange](https://www.opavote.com/results/5206745230082048) looks to have been decided by 1.6 vote (a fractional number; this is a property of the STV system).

<sub>Inspired by [I appealed against a suspension, but the appeal is still pending. Am I going to miss the election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350978/295232)</sub>

Comment: A good case could have been made in 2018 to appoint 4 mods instead of 3.

Comment: I don't know if in any mod election "exhausted" got more votes then an elected person.

Comment: It's probably on a smaller site. With less votes, you probably also get smaller absolute margins.

Comment: [Another close one.](https://www.opavote.com/results/4969828467081216/0) Victory in the last round was decided by less than 4 votes out of a total of 798 votes cast (**0.005%**). [And here](https://www.opavote.com/results/5724087510892544/0), a difference of 5 votes in the last round out of a total of 511 votes cast (**0.01%**).

Comment: The [2020 election on Math SE](https://www.opavote.com/results/6576975779987456) is also worth mentioning, which was decided by a margin of 13 votes out of 2368 total votes (**0.5%**). @Rand 4/798 is around 0.005, which is 0.5% and not 0.005%.

Answer (score 35):

It appears that [today's results from the Code Review election](https://www.opavote.com/results/5607078484770816) resulted in 224.05 "votes" for Mast and 224.32 "votes" for Peilonrayz, so a difference of 0.27 out of 767 total ballots:

[image]

This is **even closer** than the other [answer by Rand al'Thor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355879/391772) since the difference in voting percentage was less than 0.1%, versus 0.2% in that case!

However, that election on Biblical Hermeneutics was closer in a different sense, since there were 3 candidates almost neck-and-neck with each other in the final rounds, for the last 2 positions, whereas in Code Review there were only 2 candidates neck-and-neck with each other in the last round, competing for one position.

Comment: Higher precision percentages between the two answers for anyone interested.
(Steve Taylor - Tony Chan) / total_votes = (26.939782 - 26.708812) / 110 = 0.23097 / 110 = 0.21% and
(Peilonrayz - Mast) / total votes = (244.321312 - 244.053816) / 767 = 0.267496 / 767 = 0.0348%

Comment: Side note: In the aftermath of this election, Mast was added as a 5th mod to Code Review, as mentioned in this Code Review Meta post: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10677/31562

Answer (score 18):

In the absence of any mention of any other election even remotely as close as this, I'm going to propose that the likely answer is the [2020 Biblical Hermeneutics moderator election](https://www.opavote.com/results/6610233599197184/0), which finished today (27 October 2020). It was a three-slot graduation election, with just four candidates. In the final round of vote counting, the difference between the 3rd and 4th candidates was just **0.2 votes**, with the losing candidate just 0.15 votes below the threshold. There were a total of 110 users voting, making this difference **0.2%** of the overall electorate.

Answer (score 1):

This week we had two very close elections, and unlike the case of the [April 2021 Code Review election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363798/391772) in which the race was close between 3 users competing for 2 positions (and eventually it was decided that all three of them would become a ♦mod), both of these recent July 2021 elections were close between 4 users competing for 3 positions, and the *4th place candidate* was within 2% of the *1st place candidate* in both instances!

### [The Great Outdoors, July 2021](https://www.opavote.com/results/5438312878702592)

[image: The Great Outdoors, election results 2021. See here for original source: https://www.opavote.com/results/5438312878702592]

### [Islam, July 2021](https://www.opavote.com/results/5677149970235392)

[image: Islam election results, original source: https://www.opavote.com/results/5677149970235392]

Comment: Your two elections have far higher margins than the 2020 Biblical Hermeneutics moderator election.